# I received many notifications from Synology NAS: "The IP address x.x.x.x experienced 10 failed attempts when attempting to log into SSH"

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, nas, synology

I received many notifications from Synology NAS:

> The IP address x.x.x.x experienced 10 failed attempts when attempting to log into SSH.

How can this be possible though both SSH service is not turned on, and port 22 is blocked with the Synology Firewall? Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that there was an attempt so it just says that there was someonewho trying to access via ssh/port 22 and failed - so as you may hopefully understand by disabling ssh and blocking port 22 you can make your system non accessible but you can not make others not trying it

Comment: ok thank you.
I thought, that they have access because it shows in the notification, that they used Username "xxxxx" and a Password.